# Rails Nested Attribute Id Saving but not item

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So in this little rails app I'm building, I have a nested form of freelancers and trades.  Problem is when I try to create a new freelancer and save it, it saves everything but the trade name.

This is what my controller looks like:

```
class FreelancersController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @freelancers = Freelancer.all
  end

  def show 
    @freelancer = Freelancer.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
   @freelancer = Freelancer.new
   @trade = Trade.new
  end

  def create
    @freelancer = Freelancer.new
    @freelancer.firstname = params[:freelancer][:firstname]
    @trade = Trade.new
    @trade.name = params[:trade_attributes]
    @trade.save
    @freelancer.trade = @trade
    @freelancer.save
    redirect_to freelancer_path(@freelancer)
  end

  private

  def freelancer_params
    params.require(:freelancer).permit(:firstname, trade_attributes: [:id, :name])
  end
end
```

This is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@freelancer) do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.label :firstname %></br>
  <%= f.text_field :firstname %></p>

  <%= f.fields_for :trade do |trade| %>
    <p><%= trade.label :type %>
    <%= trade.text_field :name %></p>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "New Freelancer" %>
<% end %>
```

Freelancer Model:

```
class Freelancer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trade
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :trade
end
```

Trade Model:

```
class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :freelancers
end
```

For Freelancer it save the id, firstname, and trade_id.  For trade it only saves id.  The name is not being set.  I thought saying @freelancer.trade = @trade would work because it does in the console with no error and actually saves everything.  So I don't know how to get it to save the name within the app itself.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're attempting is mass assignment, but you haven't let Rails free to do this for you. In your `create` action you should do:

```
def create
  freelancer = Freelancer.create(freelancer_params)
  redirect_to freelancer_path(freelancer)
end
```

That should be all you need.

FYI: In your code, you were setting `@trade.name = params[:trade_attributes]` but `params[:trade_attributes]` was most likely returning `nil`. I'm pretty sure `:trade_attributes` would have been a key nested inside of `params[:freelancer]`.

For more on mass assignment in Rails: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mass-assignment-rails-and-you--net-31695 (note that the discussion on `attr_protected` and `attr_accessible` is not relevant to you since you're using Strong Parameters on Rails 4. The article has an update for Rails 4 at the end.)

Comment: So remove all of the line and just add those two?

Comment: Yes. Here's more on mass assignment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mass-assignment-rails-and-you--net-31695

Comment: shouldn't freelancer be an instance variable?

Comment: No because it's not used in a view later. The end of the create action is a redirect so a new action will be responsible for rendering view content after. Local variables should be used when an instance variable isn't needed.

Comment: So i've tried that but now I get a forbidden attributes error

Comment: Whoops, updated my answer. Should be using the `freelancer_params` method which will whitelist the attributes.

Comment: After trying this, it returns a no route matches error and all attributes are nil

Comment: Whoops, edited again. I changed `Freelancer.new` to `Freelancer.create`. This way a new Freelancer object will actually be created!